# List of VLAN IDs on ports and circuits, how to model relationships?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am trying to save a list of VLAN IDs per network port and also per network circuit. The list itself is something like this:

```py
class ListOfVlanIds(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'listofvlanids'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    listofvlanids_name = Column('listofvlanids_name', String, nullable = True)
```

And I then have a Port

```py
class Port(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ports'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    listofvlanids_id = Column('listofvlanids_id', ForeignKey('ListOfVlanIds.id'), nullable = True)
```

and a Circuit:

```py
class Circuit(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'circuits'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    listofvlanids_id = Column('listofvlanids_id', ForeignKey('ListOfVlanIds.id'), nullable = True)
```

Running code like this results (for me) in a sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError error on the ForeignKey.

Looking for the error I read I should add a relationship back from the list. I haven't found a way (or an example) where I can build this from both Port and Circuit. What am I missing?

Creating a list table for Ports and Circuits just moves the problem downstream, since a VLAN ID is it's own table... I'd love to be able to use ORM, instead of having to write (a lot of) SQL by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ForeignKey` expects a table and column name, not model and attribute name, so it should be `ForeignKey('listofvlanids.id')`.